Which type of screws needed to hang blinds with plastic plugs?
I would like to put up some blinds that need screwing (vertically and recess as it's for a bay style of window). I am renting so there are already the correct holes with grey plastic (rawl plugs?), but I am unsure what screws I need, length etc.

Dont the blinds cone with screws?

Thank you for the comment! No it says screws differ depending on wall type so they aren't included

Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

For most plastic anchors, I've found #8 or #10 sheet metal screws work well.  They are usually what comes in wall mounting kits.  Just make sure they're long enough to full expand the toggle.

You want screws where the inner diameter of them is not bigger than the opening of the anchor, and only the threads dig into the plastic.

The screw needs to expand the plug as it penetrates. The shaft of the screw should be just smaller than the plug bore diameter.
Length should be such that the screw roughly reaches the end of the plug.

The gold standard for mounting blinds, curtains, heavy mirrors, shelving, TV, towel rod - really almost anything that weighs more than a few pounds or that may have motion (blinds or curtains) or extra weight placed on it is screws into studs.
When that is not practical - e.g., the studs are not in the necessary locations, the next best thing is to add wood (plywood or dimensional lumber, depending on the situation) spanning two studs and attach the hanging items to the wood.
When that is not practical, there are various types of anchors, including the plastic ones you currently have, toggle bolts and a bunch of other types.
Are the plastic anchors enough for blinds? If the blinds aren't all that heavy, the drywall is in good shape, the anchors are installed properly, you use the right-size screws and there is no extra weight (e.g., from children pulling on the blinds) then they are probably just fine.
However, these plastic plugs deform from use. My guess is that the previous tenant put in the plugs and their own blinds and took the blinds when they left. If the landlord painted in between they likely would have removed the plugs and patched and painted over the holes. If you use the plugs now, you may find they are strong enough, or you may find out the hard way that they are only half as strong as they used to be because inserting and removing the original set of screws made the plugs loose in the drywall and/or removed enough inner plastic that new screws can't grip the plugs as well.
Assuming there are no studs in a good location, you may be better off installing your own anchors a couple of inches away from the previous set.

"screws into studs." of course this is only possible if the wall actually has studs.
